# How to prevent eclipse-integration-gradle plugin from putting subprojects among filteredResources?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, gradle-eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for a Gradle project, together with the [eclipse-integration-gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle) plugin.

When choosing the "Refresh All" menu item, the plugin invokes Gradle `:eclipse` task to refresh the `.classpath` and `.project` files. After gradle terminates, the plugin seems to automatically add all gradle subprojects to *filteredResources* in `.project` (possibly overwriting any other filteredResources generated by Gradle before). Such as:

```
<filteredResources>
    <filter>
        <id>1435224149113</id>
        <name></name>
        <type>26</type>
        <matcher>
            <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.orFilterMatcher</id>
            <arguments>
                <matcher>
                    <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
                    <arguments>1.0-projectRelativePath-equals-true-false-myProjectName</arguments>
                </matcher>
            </arguments>
        </matcher>
    </filter>
</filteredResources>
```

I do not want this for some reasons. Is it possible to turn this behavior off? Or some work-around, at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option can be disabled when you import the project.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work permanently. I know about this option - it causes the desired behavior, but for the initial import ONLY. When I run *Refresh All* later, the filteredResources appear again. What I need is a permanent equivalent of this option.

Comment: It shouldn't. The intention is that 'Refresh All' should preserve whatever you chose during import. If it does as you say, then that's a bug.  Could you please file a bug report here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS) and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Kris. I will make sure about this once more and then file the bug.

Comment: After some time, I wanted to file the bug report. Before that, I tried to reproduce the bug "from scratch". And it worked!

Comment: So, I confirm this option IS remembered permanently (and stored inside ".settings/gradle/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.refresh.prefs" file, as far as I understand).
For some reason, it didn't work for my existing workspace - even after a clean import - and even when I added the settings file.
When I deleted everything and imported the whole project again, the filteredResources are gone - and seem to stay so even after a refresh.
Thanks again.
(and sorry for the double comment - accidently submitted it too early)

Comment: Thanks for following up. I guess since its not a bug... then my answer is correct and you could accept it :-)